# How to pass const member function as non-const member function

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates, pointer-to-member

How to pass a *const member function* as a *non-const member function* to the template?

```
class TestA 
{
public:
    void A() {
    }

    void B() const {
    }
};

template<typename T, typename R, typename... Args>
void regFunc(R(T::*func)(Args...)) 
{}

void test() 
{
    regFunc(&TestA::A); // OK
    regFunc(&TestA::B); // ambiguous
}
```

Don't want to add something like:

```
void regFunc(R(T::*func)(Args...) const)
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Do you need the function to accept a function pointer?  Just taking a generic function type or a `std::function` should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not simply pass it to a generic template function:

**[see live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mRvbhhmPtNgx3s6J)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

class TestA
{
public:
    void A() { std::cout << "non-cost\n"; }
    void B() const { std::cout << "cost with no args\n"; }
    void B2(int a) const { std::cout << "cost with one arg\n"; }
    const void B3(int a, float f) const { std::cout << "cost with args\n"; }
};
template<class Class, typename fType, typename... Args>
void regFunc(fType member_fun, Args&&... args)
{
    Class Obj{};
    (Obj.*member_fun)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

void test()
{
    regFunc<TestA>(&TestA::A); // OK
    regFunc<TestA>(&TestA::B); // OK
    regFunc<TestA>(&TestA::B2, 1); // OK
    regFunc<TestA>(&TestA::B3, 1, 2.02f); // OK
}
```

**output**:

```
non-cost
cost with no args
cost with one arg: 1
cost with args: 1 2.02
```

Comment: This approach doesn't fit my situation. I need to handle the arguments(get it from something like lua_toxxxx) and the return value ( push it into something like lua_pushxxxx). I finally use function overloading to do this. so ugly but work.. :(

Answer (score 2):

No, you have to specify the cv and ref qualifiers to match. `R(T::*func)(Args...)` is a separate type to `R(T::*func)(Args...) const` for any given `R`, `T`, `Args...`.

As a terminology note, it isn't *ambiguous*. There is exactly one candidate, it doesn't match. Ambiguity requires multiple matching candidates.